# Uninstall on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall, osx-leopard

How can I completely uninstall any given program from Mac OS X Leopard (10.5)?

I'm obviously new at Mac... I've installed programs only through .dmg installers. I haven't compiled anything myself. Everything is in the Applications folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no universal uninstaller in Mac OS X like there is on Windows. You can simply delete a program to "uninstall" it, but its preferences and other files are left behind when you do this, which is probably not what you want.

However, there are third-party applications that can do this. [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) is one such program that allows you to completely uninstall other applications, including all the crap that they leave behind. It's not free, but [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) is a free equivalent that seems decent enough if you don't want to pay.

Comment: AppCleaner FTW. Awesome app!

Comment: Windows "universal uninstaller" doesn't remove the "crap that's left behind" either.  Root through the registry (at your own risk) and look at the traces of all the old stuff that's plugging up the works.  At least unused preference files in a users library on a Mac won't progressively slow down their computer.

Comment: @menns: I never claimed that it did. :)

Comment: @menns well.. it depends on the application.. some of them have really good uninstallers, that delete everything they create

Answer (score 10):

**Uninstalling applications installed by drag-and-drop**

If you installed the application by simply dragging and dropping a folder or the application's icon into your Macintosh HD > Applications folder, the application was distributed as a bundle. A bundle contains all of the components for the application in a single folder that is represented by the application's icon.

Applications that are distributed as bundles can generally be uninstalled by dragging the application's icon to the Trash. However, one should still consult the application's documentation for uninstall instructions.

**Uninstalling applications installed by running an installer**

Many applications require that you run an installer to install the application. The installer is a special program that installs all of the application's components in specific areas of your Mac OS X system. Installers are used when either the application is not distributed as a bundle, or the application requires some of its components to be installed in system-related areas outside of the Macintosh HD > Applications folder.

When uninstalling such an application, it is very important to consult the application's documentation to determine how to uninstall it. Common techniques employed by developers for uninstalling applications that were installed using an installer include:

- The application's installer includes
  an Uninstall option, which is often
  accessed by re-running the installer
  and selecting Uninstall from the
  pop-up menu where it offers options
  such as Easy Install or Custom
  Install.
- Some applications, such as Microsoft®
  Office, include an uninstaller
  application, either on the
  installation disc or installed along
  with the application in its folder
  within the Macintosh HD >
  Applications folder.
- Some applications create an
  Installation Log file listing all of
  the components they installed and
  where these were saved. However,
  there is no standard for where
  Installation Log files are saved. You
  may be able to use Find (Finder >
  Command-F) to locate Installation Log
  files for specific applications.

**Using Find to locate and uninstall application components**

In general, it is risky to use Find (Finder > Command-F) to locate an application's components and Trash them in an attempt to uninstall an application, particularly if the application was installed via an installer.

- Searching for files matching the
  application's name or related
  information my locate many of the
  components, but some applications
  install components that are hidden,
  invisible, or both. Accordingly, Find
  may not locate all of the components.
- Some applications install kernel
  extensions, which should be unloaded
  from the running operating system
  before their files are removed.
  Starting up in Safe Mode should
  prevent any application-specific
  kernel extensions from loading.
- Some applications, particularly
  suites of applications, share code
  between multiple applications within
  the suite. Attempting to Find and
  remove the components for one
  application in a suite could render
  the other applications in the suite
  inoperable.
- One could inadvertently
  remove important system-related
  components by accident, rendering
  your entire system inoperable. This
  is particularly a risk if you are
  using Mac OS X 10.2 Jaguar or Mac OS
  X 10.3 Panther®.
- Using Spotlight™ to search for
  Installation Logs or application
  components can be problematic. Under
  Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger®, Spotlight does
  not search system-related folders or
  other folders in which an
  application's installer may have
  saved components. While it is
  possible to search for System files
  with Spotlight under Mac OS X 10.5
  Leopard®, finding all of an
  applications components may be
  equally problematic. Spotlight in
  either version of Mac OS X does not
  have a good track record of finding
  either hidden or invisible files.
- Alternatives to Find under Mac OS X
  include the UNIX® find command and
  the freeware application EasyFind
  from DEVONtechnologies.

Therefore, it is always best to consult the application's documentation, the developer's Web site, or the developer for uninstall instructions.

**Uninstalling leftover application preferences files**

After you have uninstalled an application, its preferences files may still remain on your system. This can be true even if you uninstalled the application using a developer-provided uninstaller: some uninstallers leave the associated application's preferences files in place in case you later reinstall the application.

The following information will help you to locate and trash an application's preferences The following information will help you to locate and trash an application's preferences files after uninstalling the given application:

1. An application's preferences files
   can be found in one or both of the
   following folders in the accounts of
   every user on your Mac who used the
   application:

   - Home > Library > Preferences
   - Home > Library > Preferences > ByHost

   There are copies of the preferences files in these folders on every account that used
   the application in order to permit each user to configure the application's preferences 
   to meet their own personal work styles.
2. An application's preferences files
   generally have file names:

   - Beginning with: com.developer.application_name where developer is the name of the
     company that developed or published the application, and application_name is the name of     the application.
   - Ending with the extension .plist indicating property
     list.
3. Some applications have multiple
   preferences files. For example,
   there are four preferences files
   associated with recent versions of
   iTunes®.
4. Some applications create folders
   containing their preferences, with
   the name of the preferences folder
   including the name of the
   corresponding application. Such
   folders, if extant, will also be
   found in one or both of the
   preferences folders cited in point

Source: http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/uninstallingapps.html

Comment: @Yanokwa, anyone can edit your answer, it doesn't need to be CW for that