# How to uninstall software in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/92504/uninstall-on-mac-os-x)

I'm new to Mac OS X. How do I uninstall applications and software packages, like Xcode and the iPhone SDK, Yahoo Messenger, Open Office etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, just drag the application from it's folder to the trash.  You may also use spotlight to locate files with the same name.  Most all support files for an application are small and can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If the program has a dedicated uninstaller, use it. Otherwise simply trashing the application is enough. If you want to be extra thorough, you can trawl /Library and ~/Library for left overs.