# Uninstall Bittorrent Sync

Tags: macos, uninstall, bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

How do you properly uninstall Bittorrent Sync on Mac OSX? I can't find anything in the official FAQ or the User Guide

[BitTorrent Sync User Guide](http://btsync.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BitTorrentSyncUserGuide.pdf)

[BitTorrent Sync FAQ](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/faq/sync)

Comment: You should be able to simple delete the application much like you uninstall any other application in OS X.  http://superuser.com/questions/92504/uninstall-on-mac-os-x?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound it can't be deleted because it has plugins that continue to run after quitting the application.

Comment: There is an official uninstall guide for version 2 that mentions all the things you have to do: http://help.getsync.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1940812-how-do-i-uninstall-sync-?b_id=3895

Answer (score 12):

Both of the answers above are still relevant but with Version 2 occured a new problem:

You cannot delete the sync.app because there are plug-ins running:

> 'The item “BitTorrent Sync” can’t be moved to the Trash because some of its plugins are in use.'

The quick and dirty solution: You need to quit both "Sync Finder Extension" and "CMFSyncAgent" via activity monitor, then delete sync.app.

---

Here is the funny part: If one deletes all the files mentionend (cache, preferences, app support...) inclusive "sync finder extension" in `~/Library/Containers` but not sync.app itself then the "sync finder extension" reappears in its container-folder and is loaded again after a restart.

I don't know how it gets started again, because there are no launch demons, no launch agents, no kernel extensions or startup item I could find that starts up the plug-ins. I looked in launchctl but still no luck.

Since there is no FAQ for *really* uninstalling bittorrent sync 2 I qould appreciate if someone could comment or answer this question.

Comment: There is an official way of uninstalling BitTorrent Sync now: http://help.getsync.com/customer/portal/articles/1940812-how-do-i-uninstall-sync-?b_id=3895.

Comment: 'official' uninstall guidelines are now at http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/204775029

Answer (score 6):

In Activity Monitor, search for and Force Quit "Sync Finder Extension". Afterwards you can remove BitTorrent Sync.app from Applications.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the application `/Applications/BitTorrent Sync.App`

Delete the preferences and caches.
In Terminal:

```
rm -R ~/Library/Caches/com.bittorrent.Sync/
rm -R ~/Library/Caches/com.bittorrent.Sync.DumpUploader/
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.bittorrent.Sync.*
rm -R ~/Library/Application\ Support/BitTorrent\ Sync
```

Comment: This works when downgrading from 2.0 to 1.4.111 (latest 1.4 at the time of this writing) http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/34316-latest-14-beta-desktop-build-14111/

Answer (score 2):

You can just move the application to the trash.

There is a preference file in `~/Library/Preferences/` and cache files in `~/Library/Caches/com.bittorrent.Sync/`, but you don't have to delete them.